# Map join result into DTO

Tags: jooq

I'm starting using JOOQ with dvd rental store database aka sakila. Basically, I want to fetch an actor and his roles (table I created). So far I came up with this:

```
public ActorDTO findByName(String name) {
        ResultSet actors = dsl.select()
                .from(Tables.ACTOR)
                .join(Tables.ROLE_ACTOR).on(Tables.ROLE_ACTOR.ACTOR_ID.equal(Tables.ACTOR.ACTOR_ID))
                .join(Tables.ROLE).on(Tables.ROLE.ID.equal(Tables.ROLE_ACTOR.ROLE_ID))
                .fetchResultSet();

        return null;
    }
```

I want to be able to fetch an actor and his roles into an object: a DTO. I found this article https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/03/02/jooq-one-to-many-without-dto.html but I find the solution too verbose using sfm, and using Tuple is out of question, as I prefer to use simple POJOs.

Ideally, my DTOs would be like something like:
[image]

What is your advise regarding fetching a record with associated joins?

Answer (score 0):

there is a version that uses DTO directly see https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/02/27/jooq-one-to-many.html

by verbose? are you talking abou the Tuple2 or the mapper instantiation? or is it the .as() to alias the column?

Comment: By verbose I mean the mapper instantiation and the use of as() to make the mapper working

Comment: fair enough, there is a ticket to avoid the as, also 2 of the as in the sample of not necessary. I'm also putting a ticket, if we get the query we should be able to get the field and might be able to get the keys automagically https://github.com/arnaudroger/SimpleFlatMapper/issues/690

Comment: just pushed version 8.2.0, that have better integration with the jooq model reducing the verbosity https://simpleflatmapper.org/2019/11/12/v8.2.0.html#selectquerymapper might want to check it out, no more keys or as

Comment: Looks great! I'll have a try later in the day and let you know. Thank you a lot for your effort